# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (связанно с преобразованием к float)

Tags: python, float

Есть парсер на Selenium Python. Получаю текстовое значение поля, но при попытке преобразовать его в float получаю ошибку

```
exchange_rates = float(str(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/section/div[2]/div/main/div/div[1]/div/p[1]').get_attribute('innerHTML'))[8:-4])
```

Когда убираю float() всё работает. Значения, которое я конвертирую имеет следующий вид: `27.2783`. Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: вы где-то создали переменную под названием `float`

Comment: причём внутри у неё строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написали выше, у меня была переменная с названием float, но я про неё забыл, так как она выступала итератором в цикле и больше не использовалась. Изменил название, всё заработало как надо